# Flutter, layout issue only in deploy

Tags: flutter

I have a really interesting problem that I can't get to know why this is happening while I run my code in debug mode everything is showing fine and great, but when I deploy my application with this command:

```
flutter build web --release --web-renderer canvaskit
```

I can only use canvaskit to render my screens on the web, one widget of my screen is supposed to be my footer but it's a long gray part that would not render as I want and as it is rendered in the debug mode here is it in debug mode:
[image]

and here is it in deploy:
[image]

And it is not just that much it keeps going down as this gray part and honestly have no idea why it is doing this rest of my elements are great only this part and here is a code sniped:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:responsive_builder/responsive_builder.dart';

import 'web_row_footer.dart';
class WebLayoutFooter extends StatelessWidget {
  const WebLayoutFooter({
    super.key,
    required this.sh,
    required this.sw,
  });

  final double sh;
  final double sw;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveBuilder(builder: (context, sizingInformation) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: sizingInformation.isTablet || sizingInformation.isMobile
                ? EdgeInsets.all(
                    sh * 0.05,
                  )
                : EdgeInsets.all(
                    sh * 0.15,
                  ),
            width: sw,
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        WebFooterRow(
                          icons: Icons.location_on,
                          text: 'Address:',
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        WebFooterRow(
                          text:
                              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,',
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        WebFooterRow(
                          icons: Icons.phone_in_talk,
                          text: 'Tel :+9229341037',
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        WebFooterRow(
                          icons: Icons.watch_later_rounded,
                          text: 'Response hours: 8 to 20',
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        WebFooterRow(
                          icons: Icons.mail,
                          text: 'Email: info@onlearn.com',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Spacer(),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        WebFooterRow(
                          text: 'Categories',
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        WebFooterRow(
                          onTap: () {},
                          text: 'Manage My Account',
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        WebFooterRow(
                          onTap: () {},
                          text: 'Our services',
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        WebFooterRow(
                          onTap: () {},
                          text: 'Available payment methods',
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        WebFooterRow(
                          onTap: () {},
                          text: 'more',
                        ),
                        if (sizingInformation.isMobile)
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                             const  SizedBox( height: 40),
                              WebFooterRow(
                                text: 'Links',
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                              WebFooterRow(
                                text: 'About us',
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                              WebFooterRow(
                                text: 'blog',
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  if (!sizingInformation.isMobile) const Spacer(),
                  if (!sizingInformation.isMobile)
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          WebFooterRow(
                            text: 'Links',
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          WebFooterRow(
                            text: 'About us',
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          WebFooterRow(
                            text: 'blog',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  if (!sizingInformation.isTablet &&
                      !sizingInformation.isMobile)
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: FittedBox(
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 70,
                              width: 70,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(width: 20),
                            const Text(
                              'kleeli',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 34,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: sh * 0.05,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
            child: const Center(
                child: Text(
              '© 2001-2023, All Rights Reserved',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
            )),
          )
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}
```

here is WebFooterRow widget:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class WebFooterRow extends StatelessWidget {
  String text;
  double? width;
  IconData? icons;
  void Function()? onTap;
  WebFooterRow({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    this.width,
    this.icons,
    this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: width,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            icons != null
                ? Icon(
                    icons,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 20,
                  )
                : const SizedBox(),
            icons != null ? const SizedBox(width: 10) : const SizedBox(),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                text,
                maxLines: 3,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and lastly, this is my flutter version:

```
Flutter 3.13.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ff5b5b5fa6 (4 weeks ago) • 2023-08-24 08:12:28 -0500
Engine • revision b20183e040
Tools • Dart 3.1.0 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running your Flutter web application in release mode locally for debugging.
This will allow you to inspect any errors or layout issues that may not be visible in debug mode.

You can do this by running the following command:

```
flutter run -d web --release
```